# Google Sheets - Parse Number / Currency

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. I have a column with a set of strings e.g. '£3.36'. Now I wish for these to be treated as a number/currency and not as a string, as I am unable to mathematically manipulate them otherwise.

I have tried removing the £ by using =Right() and =LEN(), but unfortunately, sheets still considers them to be a string.

I have tried changing the format of the cell and selecting currency, but this does not work either.

I have also tried =TO_PURE_NUMBER(), but this didn't work for me either.

Has anybody got any suggestions?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that. =right(x,len(x)-1) does actually work!

Comment: dont forget to multiplie it by *1 to get a real number